# Java Generics -> Function return type

Tags: java, generics

I have a situation like this:

I have a class which looks like:

```
public class TestClass<T> {
   // class body here...
}
```

And I have a method that looks like this:

```
public class AnotherTestClass<K> {
     private TestClass<K> testClass;

     public AnotherTestClass(TestClass<K> testClass) {
         this.testClass = testClass;
     }

     public K testMethod() {
         //call methods on param object and pass a value of the same type as testClass.
         K returnVal = this.testClass.doSomething();
         return returnVal;
     }
}
```

Now I have a factory method which returns an object of type `TestClass<?>`

```
public TestClass<?> sampleFactory(int i) {
       if( i==1 ) 
           return new TestClass<Integer>();
       if( i==2 ) 
           return new TestClass<Double>();
       if( i==3 ) 
           return new TestClass<String>();
}
```

But I cant use that method to pass parameter to my `testMethod`. Whats the solution for this?

Currently I am writing `if else` chain blocks to get correct instance. I know its not correct as its impractical to write `if else` blocks when there are multiple parameters like the one above.

Please suggest an elegant way for this.

EDIT: Sample usage:

```
package my;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericsSpike {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        TestClass1< ? > tc1 = new TestClass1<Integer>( 123 );
        TestClass2< ? > tc2 = new TestClass2<Integer>( 123 );
        AnotherTestClass< ? > atc = new AnotherTestClass<Integer>( tc1, tc2 );
        atc.testMethod();
    }
}

class TestClass1<T> {
    private T value;

    TestClass1( T val ) {
        value = val;
    }

    // class body here...

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class TestClass2<T> {
    private T value;

    TestClass2( T val ) {
        value = val;
    }

    // class body here...

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class AnotherTestClass<K> {
    public TestClass1<K> testClass1, testClass2;

    public AnotherTestClass( TestClass1<K> testClass, TestClass2<K> testClass2 ) {
        this.testClass1 = testClass;
    }

    public K testMethod() {
        //Any logic can come here.
        System.out.println( testClass1.getValue() );
        System.out.println( testClass2.getValue() );
        return testClass1.getValue();
    }
}
```

In this case, if `tc1` and `tc2` are coming from a factory which creates these objects, I want to know whats the decent way to create instance of `AnotherClass`

Comment: what is your testMethod supposed to do? and can you show your factory method?

Comment: In order to clarify could you add an excerpt of the `if/else` you want to replace

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have edited the question. Please let me know if I need to add some more things.

Comment: You can parametrize method will needed type. I've just added answer with sample code.

Comment: Your example doesn't have much context, so it's hard to recommend anything.  For example, what's the return value of `testMethod`?  `method` is not a valid return type; did you mean `void`?  If it's a void method, then it could be that `K` has no benefit in `testMethod` and you could just accept a `TestClass<?>` instead.  But it's all speculative.  More likely you need to correct your factory as it's useless to have a generic factory that returns a generic type that is unknown at compile time.

Comment: @MarkPeters, I have updated my question. Return type is `K` in the method. And sorry I dunno how to fix that factory. So kindly suggest a way

Comment: Can you show the code that brings this all together?  i.e. instantiates `AnotherTestClass`, calls and stores the result of `SampleFactory`, etc?  The usefulness of Generics is all about the code that calls your method, not the method themselves.

Comment: I have just explained a sample scenario above. And edited the question.

Comment: @LPD: I see no such scenario or example code.  You added a comment to `testMethod` but that's not what I'm asking for.  What I'm asking for is sample code that would *use* both `testMethod` and `sampleFactory`.  Almost invariably, if the type parameter is only known at runtime, you wouldn't be gaining anything by making `testMethod` generic as `K` would never resolve to anything at compile time.  The lack of good answers shows how much your question lacks context (despite the bizarre number of upvotes it's getting).

Comment: Whenever you use generics, I think it is important to ask yourself a question: "What are the semantics of the type parameter?"  For collections, the semantics are easy: List<String> is "a List of String instances."  In your case, I don't really know what TestClass<?> or even TestClass<Integer> is intended to represent.  As others have said, you haven't given us enough to go on.  In general, if you have a method that is returning an object whose type lies within a family of types, you ought to be using an interface as the return type anyway (J. Bloch, Effective Java, 2nd Ed).

Comment: @MarkPeters, I have added more code that I was thinking. Hope this helps now.

Comment: @LPD: Your code is inconsistent.  Does the constructor take a `TestClass` or does `testMethod` take a `TestClass`, or both?  You always ignore the result of `testMethod`, so what does it matter if it returns a `K`?  I'm trying to convince you that a good recommendation will recognize the context and nuances of your specific problem, but you keep giving flawed or inconsistent examples.  It's really hard to help you until you spend some time getting your question to a higher quality.

Comment: That was a miss from my side. Updated the actual code that am trying to work. To get to the point, I need to find a way to instantiate the obj of class AnotherTestClass in a clean way. My code currently gives an error there understandably.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is with this method:

```
public TestClass<?> sampleFactory(int i) {
```

The `?` wildcard type means "some type, but I don't know what".  So you can get a value of type `TestClass<?>`, but it's not useful to you, because you can't meaningfully interact with the type `?` -- you can't create values of type `?` (except for null) and you can't call methods on type `?` (except methods of `java.lang.Object`).

What you really want is something like:

```
public <T> TestClass<T> sampleFactory(TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
```

That is, if you want your factory to give you back values parameterized by different types, you need to give it something that tells it what type you want.  Unfortunately, `int` isn't enough -- **you** may know that `i==1` means the type will be `Integer`, but the compiler doesn't know that.

Your description of your problem is a bit too vague for me to understand what you're really trying to achieve, but my guess is that what you really need is either something like [super type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) or maybe something like Guava's [`ClassToInstanceMap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#ClassToInstanceMap).

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use raw `AnotherTestClass` type

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass<?> tc = new TestClass<Integer>();
        AnotherTestClass atc = new AnotherTestClass();
        atc.testMethod(tc);
    }
}

class TestClass<T> {

// class body here...

}

class AnotherTestClass<K> {

    public void testMethod(TestClass<K> param) {
    }
}
```

compiles fine. But **it's not good idea to use raw types** in general case

Comment: Will this not throw any exception for any reason whatsoever? Is it safe to use?

Comment: @LPD, My exact code (with empty methods etc) runs fine. I am not sure will it work in your concrete case or not. It depends on how `K` is used in `testMethod`

Comment: I compiled the same. It runs. But i dunno how safe it is

Comment: @LPD. The only problem I can imagine is when you will use objects of some type as objects of another type e.g `tesMethod` will return `Integer`, you'll get it as `Object` because you use raw type and then you will cast it to `String`, because you do think that `K` was String , not `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

Java Doc says:

> The type of a constructor, instance method, or non-static field M of a raw type C that is **not** 
>   inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the erasure of its type in the generic 
>   declaration corresponding to C. The type of a static member of a raw type C is the same as its 
>   type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

Type erasure comes into picture even though the method's type signature doesn't use any type parameters of the class itself,

This is what your method becomes,

```
public method testMethod(TestClass param) {
}
```

Your factory method which returns an object of type `TestClass<?>`, cannot be accomodated in above method.

Comment: I understand. So if else blocks are the only solution??

Comment: This has nothing to do with erasure.  The problem occurs when not using raw types at all.  In fact, with raw types, it actually will work with some warnings (see other answers).  It's **only** in the non-raw case that the compiler error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Using this one you'll be able to pass parameter to your `testMethod`:

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Func {

    static class TestClass<T> {
    }

    static class AnotherTestClass {

        public <K> TestClass<K> testMethod(TestClass<K> param) {
            return param;
        }
    }

    static class Factory {

        public static <E> TestClass<E> sampleFactory(int i) {
            if (i == 1)
                return (TestClass<E>) new TestClass<Integer>();
            if (i == 2)
                return (TestClass<E>) new TestClass<Double>();
            if (i == 3)
                return (TestClass<E>) new TestClass<String>();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnotherTestClass().testMethod(Factory.sampleFactory(1));
    }

}
```

Comment: Type of returned value is known only in runtime in OP's example (depends on argument to factory method)

Comment: Not really, you're specifying type in source code so it must be known at compile time. Right? :-)

Comment: Emm, no. Consider case `sampleFactory(getIntFromUserInput())`

Comment: Yes @RiaD. I was about to say the same thing. And `getIntFromUserInput` is actually read from oracle table. So anyway we will have to fall back to `if else` blocks.

Comment: @RiaD: Generic types that are only known at runtime are more often than not completely useless due to erasure.

Comment: Ok, ok, ok, apologies - I misread question. Posting new solution.

Comment: @PetroSemeniuk thanks. But I will get into this `if else` blocks.. What if there are multiple parameters like this, then I will get into big set of combinations. Is that the only way is what am wondering about.

Comment: Should that be `<E> TestClass<E> sampleFactory(E i)`? Otherwise the `E` type parameter can't be inferred because it's never used, right?